# Multi-condition IF conditions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to loop over an array, skipping sertain product types. The issue i have is that it does not skip over them. The same thing happens no matter if the product type is in the skip list or not.

```
for i in source:
    if (i["product_type"] == 00 and i["product_type"] == 35 and  i["product_type"] == 72):
        print i["product_name"] + " has been skipped"
    else:
        # Upload product
```

Comment: Did you mean `or` instead of `and` ? Surely a product_type can only be one thing, it can't be 00, 35, and 72 at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you simply can't have all those conditions in one statement. One item can not have multiple values for the same attribute. Your variable `i` only has one `product_type` attribute so what you are actually looking for is a way to test against *any one* of the options:

```
if i["product_type"] == 0 or i["product_type"] == 35 or  i["product_type"] == 72:
  #
```

You want to use the `or` operator instead of the `and` operator.

Here is a much more readable version of your code (assuming that your product type value is int:

```
if i["product_type"] in [ 0, 35, 72 ]:
  print i["product_name"] + " has been skipped"
else:
  # Upload product
```

This code will check to see if the `product_type` value is referenced in the list:
   `[ "00", "35", "72" ]`.

---

As a final note, you are not required to wrap your conditional statement with parethesis (as you are with JS/PHP for example). You can simply omit them:

```
if "foo" in [ "foo" ]:
  pass
```

Works the same as

```
if ("foo" in [ "foo" ]):
  pass
```

Comment: The values in your list in the second alternative should be ints not strings

Comment: @Cyber - how could `00` be an int?

Comment: because they are using Python 2.x, look at their `print` statement.... oh I get your point, yes that would be interpreted as `octal` (though for `0` they got lucky)

Answer (score 0):

You should `or` those together instead of `and`, since `i["product_type"]` can only have a single value, I assume that is simply a typo.

```
if (i["product_type"] == 0 or i["product_type"] == 35 or i["product_type"] == 72):
```

However, it is easier and more concise to use the following

```
if i["product_type"] in (0, 35, 72):
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using a tuple and a list to contain the options?

Comment: @Lix No not really. I suppose if there were a lot of elements to check against, it would probably be best to use a set like `{0, 35, 72}` for faster membership lookup, but in this case it's trivial.

Comment: But the set would take a bit of time to create, so probably it is best to go by list/tuple if you are not doing the test very often.